# Override an array element value by matching with another array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

array1 has parent with children. array2 has few other children of parents in array1. array1 children should be replaced by children in array2

array1:

```
 {
    "name": "USA",
    "id": "country: USA",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "chicago",
            "id": "country:USA>chicago"
        },
        {
            "name": "arizona",
            "id": "country:USA>arizona"
        },
        {
            "name": "alabama",
            "id": "country:USA>alabama"
        }
    ]
},

    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "id": "country:xyz",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "id": "country:xyz>name1"
            },
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "id": "country:xyz>name2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "id": "country:abc",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "id": "country:abc>abc1"
            },
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "id": "country:abc>abc2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

array2:

```
[
{
    "name": "name3",
    "id": "country:xyz>name1"
},
{
    "name": "georgia",
    "id": "country:USA>georgia"
},
{
    "name": "name4",
    "id": "country:xyz>name4"
}
```

]

Result:

```
[
{
    "name": "USA",
    "id": "country:USA",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "georgia",
            "id": "country:USA>georgia"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "id": "country:xyz",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "name3",
            "id": "country:xyz>name1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name4",
            "id": "country:xyz>name4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "abc",
    "id": "country:abc",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "id": "country:abc>abc1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "id": "country:abc>abc2"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Code that I tried but did not work.The problem with my code is I get back the array1 as-is whereas I expect the array2 to find its parent in array1. The moment it finds the parent, it should replace array1 children with array2's data.

```
for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
var parentId = array2[j].id.substr(0, array2[j].id.indexOf('>'));
for(var k=0; k < array1.length; k++){
    if( parentId == array1[k].id){
        if(array2[j].id.indexOf(array1[k].children.id) > -1){ //found a match
            array1[k].children = [];
            array1[k].children.push(array2[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you make your arrays a bit more readable? And maybe describe in a bit more detail what isn't working in the code you gave us? btw, your array seems to have some copy/paste errors as half of the double quotes are missing :D

Comment: @Icepickle: I edited my question to make it more readable.The problem with my code is I get back the array1 as-is whereas I expect the array2 to find its parent in array1. The moment it finds the parent, it should replace array1 children with array2's data. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: When you check `parentId == array1[k].id` parentId = 'country:xyz' and array1[1].id = 'country: xyz'. be aware to the space...

Comment: @Ziki - spaces were copy paste errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to build a temporary object with keys for the grouped items and then iterate over the `array1` and if property `id` is in the `temp` object, then replace the content of the property of `children` with the new content.

```js
var array1 = [{ "name": "USA", "id": "country:USA", "children": [{ "name": "chicago", "id": "country:USA>chicago" }, { "name": "arizona", "id": "country:USA>arizona" }, { "name": "alabama", "id": "country:USA>alabama" }] }, { "name": "xyz", "id": "country:xyz", "children": [{ "name": "name1", "id": "country:xyz>name1" }, { "name": "name2", "id": "country:xyz>name2" }] }, { "name": "abc", "id": "country:abc", "children": [{ "name": "name1", "id": "country:abc>abc1" }, { "name": "name2", "id": "country:abc>abc2" }] }],
    array2 = [{ "name": "name3", "id": "country:xyz>name1" }, { "name": "georgia", "id": "country:USA>georgia" }, { "name": "name4", "id": "country:xyz>name4" }];

function f() {
    var temp = {};
    array2.forEach(function (a) {
        var key = /(country:.*)>/i.exec(a.id)[1];
        temp[key] = temp[key] || [];
        temp[key].push(a);
    });
    array1.forEach(function (a) {
        if (a.id in temp) {
            a.children = temp[a.id];
        }
    });
}

f();
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. Very elegant solution.